# Parsing nested JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, foreach

```
{
    "listing": {
        "@attributes": {
            "domain": "example.com"
        },
        "tld": "com",
        "sld": "example",
        "owner": "John Smith"
    }
}
```

I am needing to iterate through this JSON array and put the values into PHP variables so that I can return the values.

Example:

```
echo $sld;
```

would print:

`example`

Would I need to do this with a foreach loop (and if so how would I format this) or is there a easy built in function such as `extract()` that will do this?

Comment: you can just use `echo $obj->listing->sld;`

Comment: Have you looked into decoding the JSON using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? If you pass the optional `true` boolean second parameter, it will convert JSON into an associative array which can easily be manipulated with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$json = '{
    "listing": {
        "@attributes": {
            "domain": "example.com"
        },
        "tld": "com",
        "sld": "example",
        "owner": "John Smith"
    }
}';

$decoded_array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $decoded_array['listing']['sld'];//example
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
json_decode('your json string', true);
```

Which will return an associative array of your string which you can then loop though.